# Jquery Div hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, popup

I have a `div` tag which includes input controls. This `div` is opened when the user clicks on a menu item. I  want to hide this tag when the click is outside that `div` area.

Currently I am able to hide the `div` when clicking outside it, but my `div` hides when I click any of the input controls that are in the `div`. How can I solve this?

My code is:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
  var elem = $(e.target).attr('id');
  console.log(e.target);

  if (elem !== 'btnLogin') {
    // if (elem != 'TxtUserName' && elem != 'TxtPassword')
    HideLoginDetails();
  }

  if (elem !== 'hpUseFul') {
    // if(elem !== 'y')
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use hover.I want to mange this by click Only

Comment: why not use the event `focus`? and use its counter-part `blur` when you dont have the cursor on your elements? look into how jQuery use uses a `delegate` to focus on elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3fbpA/

```
var aboveDiv = false;

$('#yourDiv').click(function () { 
  aboveDiv = true;
});

$(document).click(function () { 
  if (!aboveDiv) $('#yourDiv').hide();
  aboveDiv = false;
});
```

Comment: my div is open when click on menu link.So when I click on that link document.click is called and my div is not visible its always in hide state.

Comment: I don't know how to do bubling

Comment: my div clicked event not called and needToHide remains true so my div hide

Comment: I have used div in asp.net update panel Control and that div have two input text box control.So for this reason div Click is not called?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $('the div you want').hover(function(){ 
        mouse_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if(! mouse_inside) $('the div you want').hide();
    });
});
```

Also check "[Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)".

Answer (score 0):

I have done complete bins for above issue. you can check demo link here...

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp71

**HTML**

```
<div id="loginDialog">
  <div class="field">
    <label>
      User Name: 
    </label>

    <span class="input">
      <input type="text" value="" id="txtuser" size="15"/>

    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>
      Password: 
    </label>

    <span class="input">
      <input type="password" value="" id="txtpassword" size="15"/>

    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="button" id="btn_ok" value="Login" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnLogin">
    Login
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnMenu1">
    Menu1
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnMenu2">
    Menu2
  </a>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
        $("#loginDialog").show(500);
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(e.target).attr('id');
        if ($(e.target).parents("#loginDialog").length) {
            $("#loginDialog").show();
        } else {
            if ($(e.target).attr('id') !== "btnLogin") {
                $("#loginDialog").hide(300);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#loginDialog{
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:4px;
  background:#2A2A2A;
  width:250px;
  color:#dfdfdf;
  display:none;
}
#loginDialog input{
  border:1px solid #efefef;
}
#loginDialog input[type=button]{
  background:#ababab;
}
#loginDialog input[type=button]:hover{
  background:#cfcfcf;
}
#loginDialog .field{
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
#loginDialog label{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
}
a{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:8px;
}
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp71

Comment: great job but I already solved issue by using speransky-danil answer